# How to uninstall a node module completely?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

## UPDATE

I don't have a problem with my ionic module, but with my node install(s).

It seems I have 4 node installs:
[image]

running npm start on a createreactapp installed with v15.6.0, I get:
[image]

so somehow it is using node 4.5.0.
What’s going on?

---

## Original post:

I have a module, that is malfunctioning. Uninstalling and reinstalling it ultimately results in the same error. And I can see, that uninstalling it doesn't get rid of all the files.

**Specifics:**

The module in question is Ionic

The error I'm getting ever since I tried to update it is:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/semver/internal/re.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { const { MAX_SAFE_COMPONENT_LENGTH } = require('./constants')
                                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/node_modules/semver/index.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

it is shown whenever I run an ionic command, even ionic --help

(btw. this line, that is shown from rs.js is the first line of the file)

I've tried uninstalling it with npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
and npm uninstall -g ionic
(I also once accidentally typed npm uninstall - ionic. and it did something...)

And reinstalling it with npm install -g @ionic/cli

Tried this several times.

I've also updated node to 15.6.0.

--

I have to admit I'm generally a bit confused about node modules and where they live.
Because for Ionic there are files (I'm using MacOs 11.2.3) in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/
But also in [user folder]/node_modules/@ionic
And there's a .ionic in the user folder.

Perhaps there is something I don't understand
How do I go about issues such as this?

Comment: try cleaning cache npm cache clean --force

Comment: tried reinstalling it again as described above, cleaning my cache every step of the way -> same error